# How to mutate a list-column that holds functions by converting strings to functions with the same name that are available in the environment?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I'm building a *tibble* in which I organize names (as `chr`) of data objects and the relevant wrangling function for each one.

For example, I have one function for wrangling `mtcars` and one function for wrangling `iris`:

```r
library(dplyr)

wrangle_mtcars <- function() {
  mtcars %>%
    group_by(am) %>%
    summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
}

wrangle_iris <- function() {
  iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), mean))
}
```

And I want to organize them in a table that looks like that:

```r
library(tibble)

my_trb <-
  tribble(~data_name, ~.fn_wrangling,
          "mtcars", wrangle_mtcars,
          "iris", wrangle_iris)

my_trb
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   data_name .fn_wrangling
#>   <chr>     <list>       
#> 1 mtcars    <fn>         
#> 2 iris      <fn>
```

But instead of building `my_trb` *manually* as I did above, I want to do it *programmatically*. That is, if I'm already given a 1-column table with the name of the data object, I want to simply paste a `"wrangle_"` prefix and have the tibble "understand" that I'm referring to the function with the same name that is in the global environment.

In other words I want to get from:

```r
given_table <- tibble(data_name = c("mtcars", "iris"))
```

to

```r
## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##   data_name .fn_wrangling
##   <chr>     <list>       
## 1 mtcars    <fn>         
## 2 iris      <fn>
```

By doing something like:

```r
given_table %>%
  mutate(.fn_wrangling = list(paste0("wrangle_", data_name) %>% as.name))

## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##   data_name .fn_wrangling
##   <chr>     <list>       
## 1 mtcars    <sym>  # <----| but I want it to be <fn> as in `my_trb`, not <sym>       
## 2 iris      <sym>  # <----|
```

But if I use `as.function()` instead of `as.name()` it throws an error:

```r
given_table %>%
  mutate(.fn_wrangling = list(paste0("wrangle_", data_name) %>% as.function))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `.fn_wrangling`.
>
> i `.fn_wrangling = list(paste0("wrangle_", data_name) %>% as.function)`.
>
> x list argument expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `match.fun`

```
library(dplyr)
given_table %>% 
  rowwise %>%
   mutate(.fn_wrangling = list(match.fun(paste0("wrangle_", data_name)))) %>% 
  ungroup
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  data_name .fn_wrangling
  <chr>     <list>       
1 mtcars    <fn>         
2 iris      <fn>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. `match.fun()` was what I needed. I actually prefer `purrr::map()` to save the `rowwise()` & `ungroup()`: `given_table %>% mutate(.fn_wrangling = map(.x = data_name, .f = ~ paste0("wrangle_", .x) %>% match.fun))`